# What is the purpose of Chubby Sequencers

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, consensus, paxos

While reading [article from google about chubby](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/ru//archive/chubby-osdi06.pdf), I didn't really understand the purpose of sequencers

Assume we have 4 entities :

1. Chubby cell
2. Client 1
3. Client 2
4. Service we want to use and where we will send the requests (for which we need the lock)

As far as I understood the steps are:

[image]

1. **Client 1** send `lock_request()` to **Chubby cell**, Chubby responses with `Sequencer` (assume `SequenceNumber = 1`)
2. **Client 1** send request `modify_data()` with Sequencer (SequenceNumber = 1) to Service
3. **Service** asks **Chubby cell** if SequenceNumber is valid (=1)
4. **Chubby** acknowledges it, set `LeasePeriod` (period of lock expiration to (assume) 60 seconds)
   ! during this  time no one is able to acquire the lock
5. After acknowledge, **Service** cache the data about **Client 1** (SequenceNumber = 1) for (assume) 40 seconds

Now:
if **Client 2** tries to acquire lock during these 60 seconds we set, it will be rejected by **Chubby cell**

that means it is impossible that **Client 2** will acquire the lock with the next SequenceNumber = 2 and send anything to the **Service**

As far as I understand all purpose of SequenceNumber is just for situation when 2 requests come to **Service** and **Service** can just compare 2 SequenceNumbers and reject the lower, without need to ask **Chubby cell**

but how this situation will ever happen if we have caches and impossibility to get the lock by **Client 2** while **Client 1** is holding this lock?

Comment: please post the link to the "article". do you mean the published scientific paper?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a mistake to think about timing in distributed systems with actual times (like seconds), but I'll try to answer using the same semantics.

As you said, say client1 acquires write lock named foo1,
foo here being the lock name and 1 being the generation number.

Now say, lease period is 60 seconds. 58th second now Client1 sends a write, say R1.

And soon enough, Client1 is now dead.

Now, here's the catch. You assumed in your analysis, that R1 would reach
the server inside the 2 seconds, before another client, say Client2 becomes master.

THAT'S JUST NOT CERTAIN.

In a distributed system, with fractions of milliseconds network latencies on one hand and network partitions on the other hand,
you just cannot ascertain what reaches the master first, R1 or client2's request to become master.

This is where sequence numbers would help.

Master, now having known that there is foo2, can reject R1 that came with foo1 in metadata.

Read more about generational clocks/logical clocks [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_clock#:%7E:text=A%20logical%20clock,clock%20time.%5B1%5D).

> A logical clock is a mechanism for capturing chronological and causal relationships in a distributed system. Often, distributed systems may have no physically synchronous global clock. Fortunately, in many applications (such as distributed GNU make), if two processes never interact, the lack of synchronization is unobservable. Moreover, in these applications, it suffices for the processes to agree on the event ordering (i.e., logical clock) rather than the wall-clock time.[1]